# Malloc after moving the pointer doesn't work in C?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, malloc, trie

I want to load a dictionary using `TRIE`. The first three parts of code worked as expected. But I tried to shorten the third part of the code, then it didn't work, not adding `nodes` to the `TRIE`.

Here is the declaration part:

```
#define ALPHABET_SIZE 27

// define a node for a TRIE.
struct node
{
    _Bool end_of_word;
    struct node *next[ALPHABET_SIZE];
};

// create a TRIE
struct node *root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

// create a mover.
struct node *mover = root;

// read dictionary file
FILE *dictptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
```

The main thing starts from here:

```
//load dictionary word by word;
char c;
while ((c = fgetc(dictptr)) != EOF)
{
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        mover->end_of_word = 1;
        mover = root;
    }
```

Here's where I want to optimize:

```
    else
    {
        if (c == '\'')
        {
            mover->next[ALPHABET_SIZE - 1] = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            mover = &mover->next[ALPHABET_SIZE - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            mover->next[c - 97] = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            mover = &mover->next[c - 97];
        }


        // check if memory allocation is successful.
        if (mover == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            fprintf(stderr, "unable to allocate memory to new node.\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And here's what I optimized:

```
    else
    {
        if (c == '\'')
        {
            mover = &mover->next[ALPHABET_SIZE - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            mover = &mover->next[c - 97];
        }
        mover = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: If you have e.g. `int a; if (some_condition) { a = 5; } else { a = 10; } a = 15;` what would the value of `a` be after that code? Think of that in context of your "optimized" code.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that by assigning `mover` to its element, I'm assigning a copy of that address from `root` to `mover`, not changing the address in `root` directly. Is that right?

Comment: That seems correct.

Comment: I tried to make a diagram from the perspective of a linked list. It seems that I make the `mover` point to nothing when assigning its child element value to it. That way, I break the link between `mover` and the `root` TRIE. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: Is this the actual code? You allocate size(struct note) but the struct is actually named 'node'

Comment: sorry it's a typo, it should be "node", and I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing what you did you "detached" the target of assignment from the recipient lvalue in `mover->next[...]`, thus destroying the original functionality of the code. In your version `mover->next[...]` remains unchanged.

If one literally wanted to eliminate the code duplication here, one could've done something as follows

```
    struct node **pmover;

    if (c == '\'')
      pmover = &mover->next[ALPHABET_SIZE - 1];
    else
      pmover = &mover->next[c - 97];

    mover = *pmover = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

This would be a literal implementation of your intent, which can also be rewritten as

```
    struct node **pmover = &mover->next[c == '\'' ? ALPHABET_SIZE - 1 : c - 97];
    mover = *pmover = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Although a better idea, in my opinion, would be

```
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (c == '\'')
      mover->next[ALPHABET_SIZE - 1] = new_node;
    else
      mover->next[c - 97] = new_node;

    mover = new_node;
```

(or an equivalent `?:`-based version).

Comment: Oh, I see. That's brilliant. It seems I was confused about the concept `pointer`, thus making this simple mistake. Thank you so much for helping me get through it.